# Add code before </body> only on specific pages

Tags: magento2, layout

I need to add some tracking code to specific pages before the closing body tag in my own module in Magento 2. I know I can use the file /view/frontend/layout/default.xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block ...... />
</referenceContainer>
```

But how can I specify the pages where the code should appear. I need some code to appear on the checkout page, some on the checkout success page and some on the contact page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create these layout files in your module.

Step 1.
`view/frontend/layout/my_tracking_code.xml` - feel free to rename this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
             <block ...... />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2. 
...and these ones (keep the name this time)

`checkout_index_index.xml`, `checkout_onepage_success.xml` `contact_index_index.xml`.

All of them should have this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="my_tracking_code"/> <!-- make sure the value of the "handle" attribute matches the name of the file you created in step 1.  -->
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Works good. A question though: Could it be that, with another theme or another module, those XML files were no longer valid? That through another extensions those files get replaced or changed that my code no longer gets integrated? Or is every theme adapting those XML files?

Comment: the theme layout files should be merged with the module layout files. I guess you are safe

Comment: Ok, cool. Also before.body.end puts the copyright (<small class="copyright">) template before it. I tried using after="-" on my block but still. Is there a way to put my block really at the most end of the body tag?

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in default.xml file to put tracking code exact before  tag

```
<container name="tracking.code.before.body.end" as="tracking_code_before_body_end"
               label="Tracking Code Before Body End"
               after="before.body.end">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::tracking-code.phtml"
               after="-"/>
    </container>
```

**NOTE:Your tracking code will be present in tracking-code.phtml file**

**You can also create your own module default.xml file and put above code there. In that case just use**`template="Vendor_Module::tracking-code.phtml"`

Here I had added my xml code in Magento_Theme's default.xml file.

Comment: @alobeejay Please try this answer.